# sorting a string number, angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

$scope.units gives me the data like

> [{"name":"unit 12: Abc","id":"K09A"},{"name":"Unit 4: Xyz","id":"C9J5"},{"name":"Unit 1: Acx","id":"X4C8"},{"name":"unit 4: Kxc","id":"W230"}, .....]

---

i use a filter to call the names in ng-repeat

```
ng-repeat="unit in units | orderBy: 'name'"
```

---

but it gives me the order of

> Unit 1 , 10 , 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..

---

I guess i need to parse or something. But i am unable to sort the issue. What changes can i make to get it in the integer order.

Comment: you need a custom filter that pulls the unit number out of the string and sorts numerically based on that number. http://blog.overzealous.com/post/55829457993/natural-sorting-within-angular-js

Comment: @KevinB no need for a custom filter, it's possible to use a getter function in the the orderBy filter. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Sorry, i considered a custom filter or using a function to be pretty much the same thing. The article i linked to is infact using a function, not a custom filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a getter `function` for the `orderBy` filter, like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.unitOrder = function(unit){ return parseInt(unit.name.split(' ')[1]);}
```

View:

```
ng-repeat="unit in units|orderBy:unitOrder"
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8u5hpp4w/)

Answer (score 1):

if you don't mind modifying the original array you could just sort it manually. (and skip some extra dirty checking that runs twice)

```
$scope.units.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseInt(a.name.split(' ')[1]) - parseInt(b.name.split(' ')[1]);
});
```